# Weaker notion of subgame perfect equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

It is well known that, for extensive-form games with perfect information, the notion of a Nash equilibrium is too weak, because a game may have Nash equilibria that involve "incredible threats". For this reason, the notion of a subgame perfect equilibrium (SPE) was defined, which is a pair of strategies that form a Nash equilibrium on every subgame.

However, it seems to me that this notion is actually too strong.

For example, suppose the following game:

- In the initial state, player 1 has two possible actions: A and B.

  - If player 1 chooses A, then player 2 has two possible actions: C and D

    - if player 2 chooses C, then the game ends with payoffs 100 and 90 for the two players respectively.
    - if player 2 chooses D, then the game ends with payoffs  90 and 100 respectively.
  - If player 1 chooses B, then the two players will play some really complicated game, say chess.

    - the winner of the chess game receives a payoff of 2,
    - the loser receives a payoff of 0,
    - and in case of a draw, both players receive a payoff of 1.

Finding the SPE of this game would be a hopeless task, because it would require solving the entire game of chess. However, it is immediately clear that the optimal strategy for player 1 is to choose A, and for player 2 to then choose D. For the states of the chess game, we can just select arbitrary dummy moves, since they will never be played anyway.

While the pair of strategies obtained this way will technically not be an SPE, it does capture its essence, because it's a Nash equilibrium that does not suffer from any incredible threats. So, I think there should be some intermediate solution concept, which one could probably describe as: *"a pair of strategies that results in the same terminal state as the terminal state that would be reached under the subgame perfect equilibrium."*. Such a solution concept would actually seem more useful to me than the SPE.

My question: is there a name for the solution concept that I just described? (or similar, that captures the essence of my problem) I can't imagine that this hasn't been described in the literature.

Comment: How does your desired solution concept differ from the Nash equilibrium?

Comment: It is a Nash equilibrium, but not every Nash equilibrium satisfies the condition that it results in the same terminal state as the SPE. So, it's a stronger concept.

Comment: It is not the same thing, but it is closely related: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00182-011-0301-y

Comment: Ah, ok. But in your ABCD example, every Nash equilibrium does satisfy the condition, right?

Comment: @KevinWang Yes, in my example they happen to coincide, but in general they don't.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks, that looks interesting. I will take a look at it.

Comment: just to avoid a possible "XY Problem": Why do you need such a refinement? Why can't we just talk about the SPE even though we can't compute it? We can still say things about it, like: "in the SPE of the game, Player 2 plays D and player 1 plays A."

Comment: @KevinWang Because I'm writing a paper about a game that has a similar structure, and I want to argue that I have found the 'optimal' pair of strategies for that game. Unfortunately, however, I can't say that its an SPE, because it's not. But if I only say that it's a Nash equilibrium, then I'm sure the reviewers will start yelling at me that that's not the right solution concept (and they would be right). So, I really need the proposed solution concept to quantify the 'optimality' of my strategies.

Comment: Why can't you say that it is a SPE? You only need to know that a Nash equilibrium exists in the second subgame, but you don't need to specify it. Then if you know that the payoff in the first subgame is definitely better than the payoff in the second subgame, you can describe it as @KevinWang suggested.